# Force stop query in R

Tags: r, odbc

I am using odbc in my R to get data from SQL server.
Recently, I had an issue: For some unknown reason. My query may take hours to get the result from the SQL server. It was fine before. The return data is only  10,000 rows. My data team colleagues haven't figure out the reason. My old code was:

```
getSqlData = function(server, sqlstr){
con = odbc::dbConnect(odbc(), 
                    Driver = "SQL Server", 
                    Server = server, 
                    Trusted_Connection = "True")
result = odbc::dbGetQuery(con, sqlstr)
dbDisconnect(con)
return(result)
}
```

At first, I was trying to find a timeout parameter for dbGetQuery(). Unfortunately, there is no such parameter for this function. So I decide to monitor the runtime by myself.

```
getSqlData = function(server, sqlstr){
con = odbc::dbConnect(odbc(), 
                    Driver = "SQL Server", 
                    Server = server, 
                    Trusted_Connection = "True")
result = tryCatch(
{
  a = withTimeout(odbc::dbGetQuery(con, sqlstr), timeout = 600, onTimeout = "error") 
  
  return(a)
},
   error=function(cond) {
      msg <- "The query timed out:"
      msg <- paste(msg,sqlstr,sep = " ")
      error(logger,msg)
      return(NULL)
   },finally={
      dbDisconnect(con)
      }
   )    
 return(result)
}
```

I force the function to stop if dbGetQuery() didn't finish in 10 mins. However, I get warning message as

```
In connection_release(conn@ptr) : There is a result object still in use.
The connection will be automatically released when it is closed
```

My understanding is this means the query is still running and the connection is not closed.

Is there a way to force the connection to be closed and force the query to stop?

The other thing I notice is even I set timeout = 1, it will not raise the error in 1s, it will run for around 1mins and then raise the error. Does anyone know why it behaved like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's the best answer, but I use sapply to log out all open connections through `sapply(dbListConnections(odbc()), dbDisconnect)` and connect again.